# JBOSS Teiid error when execute VDB. error message is "Error acquiring connection profile properties"

Tags: jboss, data-virtualization, teiid

Recently, i work on data virtualization to integrate data across division. After search on several software i decide to use Redhat JBOSS Data Virtualization because the software is open source. I have installed JDK , JBOSS Studio and Data Virtualization plugin to run Teiid. After that i was started new project on Teeid model project, made some configuration all the process was smooth and no error. But then when i about to make final progress which process is **execute vdb** i found error.

**The First line error message is :**

*Could Not Deploy the following VDB for execution : [Name of vdb].*

**On second line it tells that :**

*Error acquiring connection profile properties.*

When i was right click on error, and then choose event detail to pop out Event details windows.

**I found this :**

Plugin-in : org.teiid.datatools.cennectivity
Severity  : error
Message : Error acquiring connection profile properties

Exception Stack Trace :

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514)
    at org.teiid.datatools.connectivity.ConnectivityUtil.acquireDriverDefinition(ConnectivityUtil.java:190)
    at org.teiid.datatools.connectivity.ConnectivityUtil.createVDBTeiidProfileProperties(ConnectivityUtil.java:294)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.vdb.ExecuteVdbWorker.processForDTP(ExecuteVdbWorker.java:192)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.vdb.ExecuteVdbWorker.executeVdb(ExecuteVdbWorker.java:142)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.vdb.ExecuteVdbWorker.internalRun(ExecuteVdbWorker.java:104)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.vdb.ExecuteVdbWorker$1.run(ExecuteVdbWorker.java:83)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.viewsupport.UiBusyIndicator$2$1.run(UiBusyIndicator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3994)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3671)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.viewsupport.UiBusyIndicator.executeRunnable(UiBusyIndicator.java:227)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.viewsupport.UiBusyIndicator.showWhileInternal(UiBusyIndicator.java:159)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.viewsupport.UiBusyIndicator.showWhile(UiBusyIndicator.java:116)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.vdb.ExecuteVdbWorker.run(ExecuteVdbWorker.java:79)
    at org.teiid.designer.runtime.ui.actions.ExecuteVDBAction.run(ExecuteVDBAction.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

I have try to look if i'm missing something on configuration JDBC or vdb  but get no result when search that.

I wish someone could help me to solve this error. I will appreciate with any answer or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not add the JDBC driver to connect to the source. The first step is to create a connection profile to the source database using the JDBC driver (if you are accessing RDBMS) then import the metadata and then build the VDB.